# Disabling viewer options for birt reports J2EE (Eclispe)

Tags: report, birt

Hi
I have to display a birt report where I need to disable the viewer options. For example on top of every report there is run report option where I can change the parameters and see the report. I want to disable that option. 
I am displaying this report on click of a link in the browser.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer myself!! 
Changes needed to be done in ToolbarFragment.jsp.